# How to wrap or fit a table

Tags: tables

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
% \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}*{4}{|p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-1cm)/4\relax}}|}%{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Contenidos} &\textbf{Criterios Evaluaci\'on}& \textbf{Est\'andares Aprendizajes} &\textbf{Est\'andares B\'asicos} &\textbf{Competencias} \\  \hline
Movimiento   &  Justificar el car\'acter relativo del movimiento y la necesidad de un sistema de referencia y de vectores para describirlo adecuadamente, aplicando lo anterior a la representaci\'on de distintos tipos de desplazamiento  &  Representa la trayectoria y los vectores de posici\'on, desplazamiento y velocidad en distintos tipos de movimiento, utilizando un sistema de referencia & blabla & CMCT, CAA \\ \hline

Velocidad instant\'anea y velocidad media & Distinguir los conceptos de velocidad media y velocidad instant\'anea justificando su necesidad seg\'un el tipo de movimiento
  & a) Clasifica distintos tipos de movimientos en funci\'on de su trayectoria y su velocidad. b)Justifica la insuficiencia del valor medio de la velocidad en un estudio cualitativo del M.R.U.A, razonando el concepto de velocidad instant\'anea.   & blablabla   & CMCT  CAA \\ \hline


Aceleraci\'on & Expresar correctamente las relaciones matem\'aticas que existen entre las magnitudes que definen los movimientos rectil\'ineos y circulares  & Deduce las expresiones matem\'aticas que relacionan las distintas variables
en los M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., as\'i como las relaciones entre las magnitudes lineales y angulares.  &  blabla
  & CMCT\\ \hline

Movimientos rectil\'ineo uniforme & Resolver problemas de M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del SI.
  & a) Resuelve problemas de movimiento rectil\'ineo uniforme (M.R.U.), rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado (M.R.U.A.), y circular uniforme (M.C.U.), incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las
magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del SI. b) Determina tiempos y distancias de frenado de veh\'iculos y justifica, a partir de los resultados, la importancia de mantener la distancia de seguridad en carretera.
c) Argumenta la existencia de vector aceleraci\'on en todo movimiento curvil\'ineo y calcula su valor en el caso del movimiento circular uniforme.    & With IM graph should start higher, converging into without IM towards expiry.
  & CMCT CAA\\ \hline


Movimiento rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado & Elaborar e interpretar gr\'aficas que relacionen las variables del movimiento partiendo de experiencias de laboratorio o de aplicaciones virtuales interactivas y relacionar los resultados obtenidos con las ecuaciones matem\'aticas que vinculan estas variables. & a) Determina el valor de la velocidad y la aceleraci\'on a partir de gr\'aficas posici\'on-tiempo y velocidad-tiempo en movimientos rectil\'ineos. b)Dise\~na y describe experiencias realizables bien en el laboratorio o empleando aplicaciones virtuales interactivas, para determinar la variaci\'on de la posici\'on y la velocidad de un cuerpo en funci\'on del tiempo y representa e interpreta los resultados obtenidos.
  & blablabla
  &  CMCT, Cd, CAA\\ 

\end{tabular}%
% }
\caption{Perfil Competencial.}
 \label{table:PerfilCompetencial}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `tabularx` package. If your table is longer than a single page, `xltabular` might also be useful. Probably, you can also benefit from rotating the table to a landscape orientation.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
Corrected are text encoding and some small glitch in table formatting.

See, if you liked the following redesign of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, wide, label=\bfseries\alph*),
                    before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                    after =\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                   }
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
%
\caption{Perfil Competencial.} 
\label{table:PerfilCompetencial}
%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} P{17mm} *{2}{L} P{22mm} l @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Contenidos} 
    &   \thead[b]{Criterios\\ Evaluación}
        &   \thead[b]{Estándares\\ Aprendizajes} 
            &   \thead[b]{Estándares\\ Básicos}
                &   \thead{Competencias}    \\
    \midrule

Movimiento
    &   Justificar el carácter relativo del movimiento y la necesidad de un sistema de referencia y de vectores para describirlo adecuadamente, aplicando lo anterior a la representación de distintos tipos de desplazamiento
        &   Representa la trayectoria y los vectores de posición, desplazamiento y velocidad en distintos tipos de movimiento, utilizando un sistema de referencia
            &   blabla  &   CMCT, CAA       \\
\midrule
Velocidad instantánea y velocidad media
    &   Distinguir los conceptos de velocidad media y velocidad instantánea justificando su necesidad según el tipo de movimiento
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Clasifica distintos tipos de movimientos en función de su trayectoria y su velocidad.
        \item   Justifica la insuficiencia del valor medio de la velocidad en un estudio cualitativo del M.R.U.A, razonando el concepto de velocidad instantánea.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   blablabla   &   CMCT CAA    \\
\midrule
Aceleración
    &   Expresar correctamente las relaciones matemáticas que existen entre las magnitudes que definen los movimientos rectilíneos y circulares
        &    Deduce las expresiones matemáticas que relacionan las distintas variables en los M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., así como las relaciones entre las magnitudes lineales y angulares.
            &   blabla      & CMCT          \\
\midrule
Movimientos rectilíneo uniforme
    & Resolver problemas de M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del~SI.
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Resuelve problemas de movimiento rectilíneo uniforme (M.R.U.), rectilíneo uniformemente acelerado (M.R.U.A.), y circular uniforme (M.C.U.), incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del~SI.
        \item   Determina tiempos y distancias de frenado de vehículos y justifica, a partir de los resultados, la importancia de mantener la distancia de seguridad en carretera.
        \item   Argumenta la existencia de vector aceleración en todo movimiento curvilíneo y calcula su valor en el caso del movimiento circular uniforme.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   With IM graph should start higher, converging into without IM towards expiry.
                            & CMCT CAA      \\
\midrule
Movimiento rectilíneo uniformemente acelerado
    & Elaborar e interpretar gráficas que relacionen las variables del movimiento partiendo de experiencias de laboratorio o de aplicaciones virtuales interactivas y relacionar los resultados obtenidos con las ecuaciones matemáticas que vinculan estas variables.
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Determina el valor de la velocidad y la aceleración a partir de gráficas posición-tiempo y velocidad-tiempo en movimientos rectilíneos.
        \item   Diseña y describe experiencias realizables bien en el laboratorio o empleando aplicaciones virtuales interactivas, para determinar la variación de la posición y la velocidad de un cuerpo en función del tiempo y representa e interpreta los resultados obtenidos.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   blablabla   &  CMCT, Cd, CAA    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have bigger fonts (`\small` instead of `\footnotesize`) and if it is acceptable to table in landscape orientation, than you can for example use `sideways` table from the `rotating` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} % <---
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}  % <---
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, wide, label=\bfseries\alph*),
                    before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                    after =\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                   }
\small % <---
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
%
\caption{Perfil Competencial.} 
\label{table:PerfilCompetencial}
%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} P{19mm} *{2}{L} P{24mm} l @{}} % <---

% table body is the same as in the first example

    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. I have tried the 3 answers explained above and they are working perfectly.  Thanks again!

Comment: @yoyo, I have corrected text encoding and some small glitch in table in table formatting. You have two answers, so consider that now is time to accept one of them as the most suitable for you (regardless that questiont is marked as duplicate)

Comment: Many thanks but for some reasons the package \usepackage[spanish]{babel} does not work???

Comment: I managed to install the package manually. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, how can I include vertical separation in this table and change the width of the first and last columns?thanks

Comment: @yoyo, what you men with vertical separation? Width of the first column you can change simply with change the prescribed width 19mm  (` P{19mm}`) to desired one. Last column have width of the longest text in column. You can reduce it with replace `l` column specifier with `P{<width>}`, where you select `<width>` according to your needs/wishes.

Comment: This is my column specifier {\linewidth}{@{} p{19mm} *{3}{L} l @{}}  In order to change the width of the last column??Thanks

Comment: @yoyo, with this column specifier you define the same width of the first column as I do in my answer. However, by it you significantly change second, third and fourth column. The last stay the same. Please, make copy of  the table in my MWE and in copy consider your changes. Than compare both results.

Comment: what does it mean  l @{} at the end of the column specifier?

Comment: @yoyo, it eat `\tabcolsep` on the end of table. Please, see some introductory text about table settings. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. Also, please test your ideas with my MWE and see what will happen.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `longtable` environment, allow line wrapping in all five columns and omit all vertical lines to create a more open "look". As the first two data columns contain far more material than the final two, I would increase the relative width of the first two data columns.

Since you're writing in Spanish, do use accented characters -- `á` `í` `ó` `ú` and `ñ` -- directly, and do load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`. That way, hyphenation of all words can proceed as normal.

On the other hand, I don't think it's necessary to **boldface** the material in the header cells.

The following screenshot shows the first few lines of the `longtable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{longtable,ragged2e,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newlength\mylenA\settowidth\mylenA{Estándares Básicos.}
\newlength\mylenB\settowidth\mylenB{Competencias.}

\begin{document}
\begingroup

\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} P{1.2cm}
   P{\dimexpr(\textwidth-1.2cm-\mylenA-\mylenB-8\tabcolsep)/2\relax}
   P{\dimexpr(\textwidth-1.2cm-\mylenA-\mylenB-8\tabcolsep)/2\relax}
   P{\mylenA} P{\mylenB} @{}}


\caption{Perfil Competencial.} \label{table:PerfilCompetencial}\\
\toprule
Contenidos & 
Criterios Evaluación & 
Estándares Aprendizajes & 
Estándares Básicos & 
Competencias \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\tablename~\thetable, cont'd}\\
\midrule
Contenidos & 
Criterios Evaluación & 
Estándares Aprendizajes & 
Estándares Básicos & 
Competencias \\
\midrule
\endhead

\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{Cont'd on next page}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Movimiento   
& Justificar el carácter relativo del movimiento y la necesidad de un sistema de referencia y de vectores para describirlo adecuadamente, aplicando lo anterior a la representación de distintos tipos de desplazamiento  
&  Representa la trayectoria y los vectores de posición, desplazamiento y velocidad en distintos tipos de movimiento, utilizando un sistema de referencia 
& blabla & CMCT, CAA \\
\midrule
Velocidad instantánea y velocidad media 
& Distinguir los conceptos de velocidad media y velocidad instantánea justificando su necesidad según el tipo de movimiento
& a) Clasifica distintos tipos de movimientos en función de su trayectoria y su velocidad. 
b)~Justifica la insuficiencia del valor medio de la velocidad en un estudio cualitativo del M.R.U.A, razonando el concepto de velocidad instantánea.   
& blablabla & CMCT CAA \\
\midrule
Aceleración 
& Expresar correctamente las relaciones matemáticas que existen entre las magnitudes que definen los movimientos rectilíneos y circulares  
& Deduce las expresiones matemáticas que relacionan las distintas variables en los M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., así como las relaciones entre las magnitudes lineales y angulares.  
&  blabla & CMCT\\
\midrule
Movimientos rectilíneo uniforme 
& Resolver problemas de M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del~SI.
& a) Resuelve problemas de movimiento rectilíneo uniforme (M.R.U.), rectilíneo uniformemente acelerado (M.R.U.A.), y circular uniforme (M.C.U.), incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del~SI.
b)~Determina tiempos y distancias de frenado de vehículos y justifica, a partir de los resultados, la importancia de mantener la distancia de seguridad en carretera.
c)~Argumenta la existencia de vector aceleración en todo movimiento curvilíneo y calcula su valor en el caso del movimiento circular uniforme.
& With IM graph should start higher, converging into without IM towards expiry. 
& CMCT CAA\\ 
\midrule
Movimiento rectilíneo uniformemente acelerado 
& Elaborar e interpretar gráficas que relacionen las variables del movimiento partiendo de experiencias de laboratorio o de aplicaciones virtuales interactivas y relacionar los resultados obtenidos con las ecuaciones matemáticas que vinculan estas variables. 
& a) Determina el valor de la velocidad y la aceleración a partir de gráficas posición-tiempo y velocidad-tiempo en movimientos rectilíneos. b)~Diseña y describe experiencias realizables bien en el laboratorio o empleando aplicaciones virtuales interactivas, para determinar la variación de la posición y la velocidad de un cuerpo en función del tiempo y representa e interpreta los resultados obtenidos.
& blablabla &  CMCT, Cd, CAA\\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks but for some reasons the package \usepackage[spanish]{babel} does not work???

Comment: @yoyo - Please clarify what "does not work???" entails for the case at hand. (Aside: The sample document above "works" just fine.) Are you getting an error message? A warning message? If so, what does the message say? Which TeX distribution do you employ? (Sadly, my psychic cognitive abilities are utterly worthless. I won't pretend otherwise.)

Comment: It was the package [spanish]{babel} which could not be installed but I managed to install it manually.