# Formatting a table, fixed length

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} % <---
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}  % <---
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}      

\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, wide, label=\bfseries\alph*),
                    before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                    after =\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                   }
\small % <---
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\caption{Perfil Competencial.} 
\label{table:PerfilCompetencial}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} P{19mm} *{3}{L} P{25mm} l @{}} % <---

    \toprule
\thead{Contenidos} 
    &   \thead[b]{Criterios de Evaluaci\'on}
        &   \thead[b]{Est\'andares de Aprendizajes} & \thead {Actividades}
                        &   \thead{Competencias\\ (CC)}    \\
    \midrule

El Movimiento.
    &   1. Justificar el car\'acter relativo del movimiento y la necesidad de un sistema de referencia y de vectores para describirlo adecuadamente, aplicando lo anterior a la representaci\'on de distintos tipos de desplazamiento.
        &   1.1 \textbf{Representa la trayectoria y los vectores de posici\'on, desplazamiento y velocidad en distintos tipos de movimiento, utilizando un sistema de referencia.}
    & ANEXO I     &   CMCT, CAA       \\

\midrule

Velocidad instant\'anea y velocidad media.
    &   2. Distinguir los conceptos de velocidad media y velocidad instant\'anea justificando su necesidad seg\'un el tipo de movimiento.
        & \begin{enumerate} 
      \item[2.1]    \textbf{ Clasifica distintos tipos de movimientos en funci\'on de su trayectoria y su velocidad.}
       \item[2.2] \textbf{Justifica la insuficiencia del valor medio de la velocidad en un estudio cualitativo del movimiento rectil\'ineo acelerado (M.R.U.A), razonando el concepto de velocidad instant\'anea.}
        \end{enumerate} 

     &  ANEXO II   &   CMCT CAA    \\
\midrule
Aceleraci\'on.
    &   3. Expresar correctamente las relaciones matem\'aticas que existen entre las magnitudes que definen los movimientos rectil\'ineos y circulares.
        &  \textbf{3.1 Deduce las expresiones matem\'aticas que relacionan las distintas variables en los movimiento rectil\'ineo uniforme (M.R.U.), rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado (M.R.U.A.), y circular uniforme (M.C.U.), as\'i como las relaciones entre las magnitudes lineales y angulares.}
      &  ANEXO III         & CMCT          \\
\midrule
Movimiento rectil\'ineo uniforme.
    & 4. Resolver problemas de M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del SI.
        & 
        \begin{enumerate}


      \item[4.1]    \textbf{Resuelve problemas de movimiento rectil\'ineo uniforme (M.R.U.), rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado (M.R.U.A.), y circular uniforme (M.C.U.), incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del SI.}
      \item[4.2]     \textbf{Determina tiempos y distancias de frenado de veh\'iculos y justifica, a partir de los resultados, la importancia de mantener la distancia de seguridad en carretera.}
      \item[4.3]    \textbf{Argumenta la existencia de vector aceleraci\'on en todo movimiento curvil\'ineo y calcula su valor en el caso del movimiento circular uniforme.}
 \end{enumerate}          

                &      ANEXO IV        & CMCT CAA      \\
\midrule
Movimiento rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado.
    & 5. Elaborar e interpretar gr\'aficas que relacionen las variables del movimiento partiendo de experiencias de laboratorio o de aplicaciones virtuales interactivas y relacionar los resultados obtenidos con las ecuaciones matem\'aticas que vinculan estas variables.
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item[5.1]   \textbf{Determina el valor de la velocidad y la aceleraci\'on a partir de gr\'aficas posici\'on-tiempo y velocidad-tiempo en movimientos rectil\'ineos.}
        \item[5.2]    Dise\~na y describe experiencias realizables bien en el laboratorio o empleando aplicaciones virtuales interactivas, para determinar la variaci\'on de la posici\'on y la velocidad de un cuerpo en funci\'on del tiempo y representa e interpreta los resultados obtenidos.
            \end{enumerate}
      &  ANEXO V        &  CMCT, Cd, CAA    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{sidewaystable}

Se destacan en \textbf{negrita} en la tabla anterior los est\'andares b\'asicos evaluables, sin el conocimiento de los cuales el alumno no puede aprobar la asignatura.
```

Comment: How can I tide up this table? How to indent the columns?

Comment: please make your example a complete document that shows the problem and can be used to test answers. Also ask the question in the main question, not in comments as the comments may be removed. Your example uses many commands not defined by default and not defined here, `sidewaystable`, `P`  columns, `\toprule` etc. I can guess definitions for some but not all, but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: You should really, really indicate that the code is straight from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516924/5001) by [@Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko). It's nothing but common courtesy to acknowledge one's intellectual debt, even in non-academic settings.

Comment: I am very sorry and understand all your comments but honestly, I am not very good at asking questions here (I get very confused) so before it I have tried to solve it by myself but I can't.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to change about the table. What does "tide up"  mean and which column(s) do you want to indent?

Comment: Please also explain the column specifiers. You declare a total of 6 columns, but in the body of your table you only use 5.

Comment: I would like to indent all columns if possible and to adjust the columns, per example column 3 may need more width than columns 4 and 5. Column 4 seems to be more to the left than centered.

Comment: As much as I have tried to look up on internet I can not understand the column specifiers.

Comment: I get that you want different column widths, but what does indent mean in that case? Does it refer to the enumerate items and their numbers? Could you show a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: I mean Indent the text in column 3 but if it is not possible, it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one unused column; the last two columns should both be `l`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} % <---
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}  % <---
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}      

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!htp]
\setlist[enumerate]{
  nosep,
  wide,
  label=\bfseries\alph*),
  before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
  after =\vspace{-\baselineskip}
}
\small % <---
%\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\caption{Perfil Competencial.} 
\label{table:PerfilCompetencial}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} P{19mm} *{2}{L} ll @{}} % <---

    \toprule
\thead{Contenidos} 
    &   \thead[b]{Criterios de Evaluaci\'on}
        &   \thead[b]{Est\'andares de Aprendizajes} & \thead {Actividades}
                        &   \thead{Competencias\\ (CC)}    \\
    \midrule

El Movimiento.
    &   1. Justificar el car\'acter relativo del movimiento y la necesidad de un sistema de referencia y de vectores para describirlo adecuadamente, aplicando lo anterior a la representaci\'on de distintos tipos de desplazamiento.
        &   1.1 \textbf{Representa la trayectoria y los vectores de posici\'on, desplazamiento y velocidad en distintos tipos de movimiento, utilizando un sistema de referencia.}
    & ANEXO I     &   CMCT, CAA       \\

\midrule

Velocidad instant\'anea y velocidad media.
    &   2. Distinguir los conceptos de velocidad media y velocidad instant\'anea justificando su necesidad seg\'un el tipo de movimiento.
        & \begin{enumerate} 
      \item[2.1]    \textbf{ Clasifica distintos tipos de movimientos en funci\'on de su trayectoria y su velocidad.}
       \item[2.2] \textbf{Justifica la insuficiencia del valor medio de la velocidad en un estudio cualitativo del movimiento rectil\'ineo acelerado (M.R.U.A), razonando el concepto de velocidad instant\'anea.}
        \end{enumerate} 

     &  ANEXO II   &   CMCT CAA    \\
\midrule
Aceleraci\'on.
    &   3. Expresar correctamente las relaciones matem\'aticas que existen entre las magnitudes que definen los movimientos rectil\'ineos y circulares.
        &  \textbf{3.1 Deduce las expresiones matem\'aticas que relacionan las distintas variables en los movimiento rectil\'ineo uniforme (M.R.U.), rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado (M.R.U.A.), y circular uniforme (M.C.U.), as\'i como las relaciones entre las magnitudes lineales y angulares.}
      &  ANEXO III         & CMCT          \\
\midrule
Movimiento rectil\'ineo uniforme.
    & 4. Resolver problemas de M.R.U., M.R.U.A., y M.C.U., incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del SI.
        & 
        \begin{enumerate}


      \item[4.1]    \textbf{Resuelve problemas de movimiento rectil\'ineo uniforme (M.R.U.), rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado (M.R.U.A.), y circular uniforme (M.C.U.), incluyendo movimiento de graves, teniendo en cuenta valores positivos y negativos de las magnitudes, y expresando el resultado en unidades del SI.}
      \item[4.2]     \textbf{Determina tiempos y distancias de frenado de veh\'iculos y justifica, a partir de los resultados, la importancia de mantener la distancia de seguridad en carretera.}
      \item[4.3]    \textbf{Argumenta la existencia de vector aceleraci\'on en todo movimiento curvil\'ineo y calcula su valor en el caso del movimiento circular uniforme.}
 \end{enumerate}          

                &      ANEXO IV        & CMCT CAA      \\
\midrule
Movimiento rectil\'ineo uniformemente acelerado.
    & 5. Elaborar e interpretar gr\'aficas que relacionen las variables del movimiento partiendo de experiencias de laboratorio o de aplicaciones virtuales interactivas y relacionar los resultados obtenidos con las ecuaciones matem\'aticas que vinculan estas variables.
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item[5.1]   \textbf{Determina el valor de la velocidad y la aceleraci\'on a partir de gr\'aficas posici\'on-tiempo y velocidad-tiempo en movimientos rectil\'ineos.}
        \item[5.2]    Dise\~na y describe experiencias realizables bien en el laboratorio o empleando aplicaciones virtuales interactivas, para determinar la variaci\'on de la posici\'on y la velocidad de un cuerpo en funci\'on del tiempo y representa e interpreta los resultados obtenidos.
            \end{enumerate}
      &  ANEXO V        &  CMCT, Cd, CAA    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Don't specify just `[h!]`, because this might block the queue.

I see no need to reduce `\tabcolsep`.

[image]

Comment: Just to understand better tables-format: What really was the problem was this command?   before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}  Anyway, the problem is solved. Thanks a lot and again, sorry about my inexperience with table, I find them really confusing.

Comment: @yoyo: The actual problem was your use of `*{3}{L} P{25mm}` instead of `*{2}{L} l`.

Comment: okey. I see it now.thanks